# Can't run symofny 2 on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, symfony, xampp

Using MAC OS X Lion. Newest Version XAMPP.

My Problem:

```
Warning: require_once(/Users/test/workspace/Symfony/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/test/workspace/Symfony/app/autoload.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Users/test/workspace/Symfony/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Users/test/workspace/Symfony/app/autoload.php on line 25
```

Configuration: XAMPP:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sym.tolisto.de
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /Users/test/workspace/Symfony/web
<Directory /Users/test/workspace/Symfony/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Symfony 1.4 works. But Symfony2 doesn't Why?

Using MAC OS X Lion. Newest Version XAMPP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you started to check for the existence of the "required" file?

Answer (score 2):

first run web/config.php and check it out is every thing is ok for symfony2 framework